# page doesn't display what is inside <script>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a script to take input from the user and greet him

But nothing happens on the page. There is an input form which takes an input and submits it. That's it. It doesn't print anything then.

What I'm doing wrong? How can I fix it?

I expect the code to print something like "Hello, Sam" where Sam is the user's input.

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
   let inp = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
   console.log("Hello, " + inp);
</script>
```

Comment: As you can see in the snippet, it does run and does display something in the console. But not when you submit

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to not submit the form or you will reload the page
2. You are using console.log to show the result, so you need to look in the console for the text. Press F12 or right-click and inspect and look in the console tab
3. You are not actually doing anything with the code that is related to the form submit event - your script is just running with what is in the form at load time

Using a [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)  event listener, you can do this - I am using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to format the text:

```js
document.getElementById("nameForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // we cancel the submit event
  let firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `Hello <b>${firstName}</b>`;
});
```

```html
<form id="nameForm">
   <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create `.onsubmit` event for that form, so when the submit button clicks, do your task in the callback function. Don't forget to do `return false` if you want to disable redirect after submission.

If you want the simple answer, here it is:

```html
<form id="form" action="#">
   <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
   let form = document.getElementById('form');
   form.onsubmit = function(event) {
     let data = event.target.elements;
     let inp = data.firstName.value;
     console.log("Hello, " + inp);
     return false;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: It is recommended to use eventListener and preventDefault instead of onevent and return false. If your code has errors, the form will submit anyway because return false is never reached. Also this.firstName.value is simpler than your two lines to get the value

Comment: Please edit my answer for a better solution.

Comment: Why? I gave the better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75732656/295783) already :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you 

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input id="firstName" type="text">
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

<script>
  function submit() {
    let inp = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    console.log('Hello, ' + inp);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to explain what you did and why?